# SQL fetch data for the present year until previous week friday

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Am trying to fetch data in SQL until previous week Friday for the present year from the **datetime** field **fetchDate**

I tried something like this but it fetches until today

```
(year(fetchDate) = year(GETDATE()) and month(fetchDate) <= month(GETDATE()) and day(fetchDate) <= day(GETDATE()))
```

whereas

```
(year(fetchDate) = year(GETDATE()) and month(fetchDate) <= month(GETDATE()) and day(fetchDate) <= day(DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),4)))
```

brings me data only for the present month of the year until last week.

Comment: have you tried a search engine with "sqlserver last monday" (or any other day really). it'll provide you with an idea how to calculate the last friday. then your query should be like: year is same year and DATE <= {lastfridaydate}, you don't have to go down into month/day functions for that.

Comment: Some sample dates would really help me understand what you mean by "previous week Friday".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need is the following:

```
WHERE YEAR(fetchDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
AND fetchDate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ((7 + WEEKDAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) - 4) % 7) DAY)
```

We get how many days ago last week's Friday was with:

```
((7 + WEEKDAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) - 4) % 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather go for the following solution as it is *sargable*. Inside the WHERE predicate we are not wrapping the fetchdate into a function (e.g. `YEAR(Fetchdate)`), the query optimizer could use existing indexes and does not have to scan the whole table. Especially for BI workloads where this query is common, it is extremely important to optimize for that a lot of records are queried. It comes at the cost of *little less* readability

```
declare @tab table
(
    fetchdate datetime
)
insert into @tab
values ('2019-01-01'),('2019-03-15'),('2018-12-31'),('2019-03-16')
SELECT 
*,
case when datepart(weekday, getdate()) >5 then
 DATEADD(DAY, +4, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, getdate()), 0)) 
else DATEADD(DAY, -3, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, getdate()), 0)) end as TestLastFriday,
DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) as TestFirstDayOfYear
FROM @tab
where 
    fetchdate <= case when datepart(weekday, getdate()) >5 then DATEADD(DAY, +4, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, getdate()), 0)) 
                 else DATEADD(DAY, -3, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, getdate()), 0)) end and 
    fetchdate >= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```